# Render base64 image in vue.js

Tags: image, vue.js, base64

Can someone help me display a Base 64 encoded image using vue.js?

Basically I have an image object:

```
img = {
  encodedImage: '/9x/4AFQSkZJRgABAXAASABIAAD...'
}
```

I know that in pure HTML i can do something like:

```
<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

In vue, i have tried the following:

```
<img :src="img.encodedImage" />
<img v-bind:src="img.encodedImage" />
<img :src="{{img.encodedImage}}" />
<img v-bind:src="{{img.encodedImage}}" />
```

Here's my full vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="img.encodedImage">
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props: [ 'img' ]
}
</script>
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set `img` to be a property of the vue instance? Or are you just trying to reference a plain javascript object?

Comment: it's part of my vue instance @thanksd

Comment: Can you show how you've set that in your vue instance?

Comment: sure - just updated my question. note - the `img` object comes in as a prop

Comment: And how are you passing `img` to the component?
 BTW this is working for me https://jsfiddle.net/1eddx72k/

Comment: ah - my `encodedImage` is in the raw format w/o the `data:image/png;base64, `... i'll just add that in manually. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 48):

In `vue.js`, it'll look like:

```
<img v-bind:src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imageBytes" />
```

Comment: This worked for me with slight change - <img v-bind:src="imageBytes" />

Answer (score 18):

To display any [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in a vue component you can do something like this:

**Data URI way**

```html
<template>
  <img :src="`data:image/png;base64,${img.encodedImage}`" />
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  props: ['img'],
};
```

**Recommended way**

```html
<template>
  <img :src="image" />
</template>
```

```js
import image from '@/assets/image.png';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Even though it's recommended, it's not practical in every situation. I created a Vue app, integrated it with a CRM and my images did not show (status 404) because of incorrect paths.The data-uri way solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have had the same issue.

Change

```
img = {  encodedImage: '/9x/4AFQSkZJRgABAXAASABIAAD...'}
```

to

```
img = {  encodedImage: 'data:image/jpg;base64,/9x/4AFQSkZJRgABAXAASABIAAD...'}
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`<img :src="'data:image/png;base64,' + item.ItemImageData ">`

Here, item.ItemImageData contains base64 image string.
As my image is png hence I used "data:image/**png**". Change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable image component:

```js
<template>
  <img v-bind:src="'data:image/gif;base64,'+ imageAsBase64" />
</template>

<script>
import fs from "fs";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageAsBase64: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.imageAsBase64 = fs.readFileSync("./assets/progress-bar.gif", "base64");
  }
};
</script>
```

Then use in your components:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <DataImage></DataImage>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DataImage from "./DataImage.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    DataImage
  }
}
</script>
```